# How do I obtain weighted average weights using SCEUA in rtop package, R language

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, r-package, weighted-average

1. Problem Description:
   When attempting to use the sceua, I encountered the following problems.

   I want to use SCEUA to obtain weighted average weight values, involving three parameters, each with a range of 0 to 1.

   As is well known, in a weighted average, the sum of weights should be 1.

   I tried to achieve this goal by setting the implicit parameter, but couldn't achieve the expected result, and the sum of weights is not 1.

   e.g. `implicit=function(pars)(pars[1]+pars[2]+pars[3])==1`

   On the other hand, I want to save the weight value with two significant numbers.

   Despite consulting the package documentation and forums, I have been unable to resolve the issue.
2. My Operating Environment:

   - R Version: R 4.2.3
   - Operating System: Windows 10
3. Attempts at Resolution:

   - I have consulted the package documentation and attempted the suggested solutions.
   - I searched stackoverflow for similar issues but did not find any applicable solutions.
4. Additional Information:

   - If necessary, I can provide additional information, such as code examples to better elucidate my problem.

Comment: Hi lily Taylor, welcome to SO. This type of question is much easier to answer definitively if it is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE. Thanks